# php array creation on incorrect test data

Tags: php, arrays

I have been given a question:

```
 /**
 * return structure should be an array of hashmaps which looks something like
 *
 * array(3) {
 * [0] =>
 * array(2) {
 * 'min' => int(500)
 * 'max' => int(750)
 * }
 * [1] =>
 * array(2) {
 * 'min' => int(750)
 * 'max' => int(1000)
 * }
 * [2] =>
 * array(2) {
 * 'min' => int(1000)
 * 'max' => int(1250)
 * }
 * }
 *
 * @param int $min
 * @param int $max
 * @param int $incrementStep
 * @return array
 */

 function getPriceRangeCollection($min, $max, $incrementStep) {
 //code goes here
 }

 //test code - DO NOT REMOVE
 $priceRangeCollection = getPriceRangeCollection(500, 5000, 250);
 assert($priceRangeCollection[17]['min'] === 4750 && $priceRangeCollection[17]['max'] === 5000);
 assert($priceRangeCollection[9]['min'] === 2750 && 
 $priceRangeCollection[9]['max'] === 3000);

 $priceRangeCollection2 = getPriceRangeCollection(1, 100, 3);
 assert(count($priceRangeCollection2) === 33);
 assert($priceRangeCollection2[32]['min'] === 96);
 assert($priceRangeCollection2[32]['max'] === 99);
```

For this exercise, you need to create the function getPriceRangeCollection which is to create an array of value pairs (as per the example above) starting from a minimum range to the maximum range by the incremental value.

What I have so far, works for the first set of test data, but fails on the second. With assert($priceRangeCollection2[32]['min'] === 96); being 1 lower than my code produces, which is 97.

```
 function getPriceRangeCollection($min, $max, $incrementStep) {
    //code goes here
    $myArray = array();
    $index = 0;

    for( $i = $min; $i < $max; $i = $i + $incrementStep ){
        $myArray[ $index ] = array( 'min' => $i, 'max' => $i + $incrementStep );
        $index ++;
    }

    return $myArray;
 }
```

Have I missed some thing, or is the provided test data wrong?

var_dump of priceRangeCollection2:

```
 array(33) { [0]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(1) ["max"]=> int(4) } [1]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(4) ["max"]=> int(7) } [2]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(7) ["max"]=> int(10) } [3]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(10) ["max"]=> int(13) } [4]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(13) ["max"]=> int(16) } [5]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(16) ["max"]=> int(19) } [6]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(19) ["max"]=> int(22) } [7]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(22) ["max"]=> int(25) } [8]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(25) ["max"]=> int(28) } [9]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(28) ["max"]=> int(31) } [10]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(31) ["max"]=> int(34) } [11]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(34) ["max"]=> int(37) } [12]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(37) ["max"]=> int(40) } [13]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(40) ["max"]=> int(43) } [14]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(43) ["max"]=> int(46) } [15]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(46) ["max"]=> int(49) } [16]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(49) ["max"]=> int(52) } [17]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(52) ["max"]=> int(55) } [18]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(55) ["max"]=> int(58) } [19]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(58) ["max"]=> int(61) } [20]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(61) ["max"]=> int(64) } [21]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(64) ["max"]=> int(67) } [22]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(67) ["max"]=> int(70) } [23]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(70) ["max"]=> int(73) } [24]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(73) ["max"]=> int(76) } [25]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(76) ["max"]=> int(79) } [26]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(79) ["max"]=> int(82) } [27]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(82) ["max"]=> int(85) } [28]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(85) ["max"]=> int(88) } [29]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(88) ["max"]=> int(91) } [30]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(91) ["max"]=> int(94) } [31]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(94) ["max"]=> int(97) } [32]=> array(2) { ["min"]=> int(97) ["max"]=> int(100) } }
```

Warning: assert(): assert($priceRangeCollection2[32]['min'] === 96) failed in C:\xampp\htdocs\InSite\php_exercise.php on line 50

Warning: assert(): assert($priceRangeCollection2[32]['max'] === 99) failed in C:\xampp\htdocs\InSite\php_exercise.php on line 51

Comment: _“which is to create an array of value pairs (as per the example above)”_ - what example above?

Comment: Question edited to provide this for you!

Comment: Please provide a dump of `priceRangeCollection2`. The test data is not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your code work perfectly if you change the test data, like this:

```
 $priceRangeCollection2 = getPriceRangeCollection(0, 98, 3);
 assert($priceRangeCollection2[32]['min'] === 96);
 assert($priceRangeCollection2[32]['max'] === 99);
 assert(count($priceRangeCollection2) === 33);
```

Comment: I don't think they will let me change the test data, to make it work

Comment: If I change it to your suggestion, then my original code works as well. So, I assume, the test data is incorrect!

Comment: yeah, that's what i think too